# Scrolling when there are two CollectionViews in ContentPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two CollectionViews in my ContentPage inside a StackLayout, one above the other. Each binds to a separate ItemsSource. Above each one I have a Label. At this point each one take up 50% of the screen and scrolls separately.

I would like everything to scroll as though it were one long list.

So I surrounded everything with a ScrollView. But then, depending on where you put your finger, the scroll may scroll the entire page (which is what I want) or just the current CollectionView.

It seems like there is no way to cancel the scroll capability of the CollectionView. Is that true? and if not, How should I set up my ContentPage ?

In the below example both CollectionViews have the same model and binding but in reality they will be different.

Here is the xaml:

```
<RefreshView
        x:DataType="local:AllRestaurantsViewModel"
        Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label
                    FontSize="Large"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Suggested Restaurants" />
                <CollectionView
                    x:Name="ItemsListView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestedRestsComments}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:SuggestedRestsComment">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding restaurantName}" />
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="13"
                                    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding CityName}" />
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>


                <Label
                    FontSize="Large"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Existing Restaurants" />


                <CollectionView
                    x:Name="ItemsListView2"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestedRestsComments}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:SuggestedRestsComment">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding restaurantName}" />
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="13"
                                    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding CityName}" />
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean want to stop scrolling when moving to another collection view? Here is a relevant discussion, may be helpful. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183309/collectionview-how-to-disable-scrolling

Comment: Unfortunately, adding KeepItemsInView like they suggest did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a try with Custom **CollectionViewRenderer** to achieve that in each platform.

For example, send a mesage in Forms:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "StopScrollinng");
}
```

Then in **iOS** `CustomCollectionViewRenderer` class stop scrolling:

```
public class CustomCollectionViewRenderer: CollectionViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<GroupableItemsView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "StopScrollinng", (sender) =>
        {
            // Do something whenever the "StopScrollinng" message is received
            if (Control != null)
            {
                NSArray s = Control.ValueForKey(new NSString("_subviewCache")) as NSMutableArray;
                UICollectionView c = s.GetItem<UICollectionView>(0);
                c.SetContentOffset(c.ContentOffset, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in **Android** `CustomCollectionViewRenderer` class stop scrolling:

```
public class CustomCollectionViewRenderer: CollectionViewRenderer
{
    public CustomCollectionViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
       
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ItemsView> elementChangedEvent)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(elementChangedEvent);
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "StopScrollinng", (sender) =>
        {
            // Do something whenever the "StopScrollinng" message is received

            this.DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.Obtain(SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), MotionEventActions.Cancel, 0, 0, 0));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

In your scrollview set InputTransparent="True" this allows the input to go through to the layer underneath.

```
<ScrollView InputTransparent="True">
```

Then leave some white space (background) on the right side of the collection views.

Now when someone swipes in the white space, the entire page scrolls. And when someone swipes inside the collection view, the collection view scrolls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is an interesting idea but not the solution I was looking for. I really just want it to behave like one long list (even though they are one list after another list). I don't think your idea is intuitive enough or standard so users will be confused. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data

the idea is to not use two separate collectionviews and merge them into one by choosing a datatemplate at runtime

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:<your namespace>.Controls"     
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>

    <controls:DataTemplateSelector1 x:Key="DataTemplateSelector1"
        Template1="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"
        Template2="{StaticResource DataTemplate2}" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
namespace <your namespace>.Controls
{
    public class DataTemplateSelector1: DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate Template1 { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate Template2 { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            //here you return which template you want to use based on the properties of "item" . e.g you can do item is SomeClass ? Template1 : Template2
        }
    }
}
```

```
<ScrollView>
    <CollectionView x:Name="collection" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelector1}"></CollectionView>
</ScrollView>
```